# Batch run maya with last recent file

Tags: command-line-arguments, maya

I try to make a batch file that basically opens all the stuff I need to work. Opening Maya is quite simple, but there's one step further i'd like to do: make it open my last opened file.
if i understand the doc [Start Maya from the command line](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-GettingStarted/files/GUID-2E5D1D43-DC3D-4CB2-9A35-757598220F22-htm.html)

I could try this:

```sh
path/to/maya.exe -command [some MEL commands that may open the last opened file]
```

But I have no clue how to MEL and I guess for it to work as a windows batch I must keep it as one command line. I try to read the docs but I fail to find anything I can make use of.

```py
python("recent = cmds.optionVar(q='RecentFilesList')[-1]; cmds.file (recent, force=True, open=True)")
```

Issues:

- I can't find a way to correctly parse the quote marks through batch to Maya.
- The file command requires to first save the file to work...

#### Solutions

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64169334/10705720):

- use `force=True`in `cmds.file (recent, force=True, open=True)` to force the file command to work without the need to save the file first
- use one backslash `\` before the commands `"` to properly parse them to Maya

```py
"path\to\maya.exe" -command "python(\"recent=cmds.optionVar(q='RecentFilesList')[-1]; cmds.file (recent, force=True, open=True)\")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Usually you replace a " with a \" to get a working mel command. So if you this could work:

   `"python(\"recent = cmds.optionVar(q='RecentFilesList')[-1]; cmds.file (recent, open=True)\")"`

But to be honest I did not test it as a commandline argument.

2. You can modify the file command with force:

   `cmds.file(recent, force=True, open=True)`

Comment: Alright, here's the solution: `"python(\"recent=cmds.optionVar(q='RecentFilesList')[-1]; cmds.file (recent, force=True, open=True)\")"` **Thanks for the help**.